# How can I make an apps script web app display as 100% of actual available height?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-apps-script, iframe

I have [this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx8ZFrd6FSGYg97Fdncsq8SKHZN0elZLkZ5ZxXfNypIo9tLt_M/exec) Google Apps Script web app.  it *should* simply show a blue background that is the height of the view-height of the screen.

Here is the code

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
     html, body {
       margin: 0px;
       height: 100vh;
       background-color:lightblue;
      }
   </style>  
 </head> 
 <body>
 </body>  
</html>
```

The problem is that the body is not displaying as 100% of the available view-height. This is because some of the view-height is taken up by the "This app was created by another user" banner.

Instead, then, a scroll-bar appears on the right (screenshot attached).  A scroll bar for the app iframe height set to 100vh + the height of the banner.

So when I add content to the body, that is greater than the height on the view-height, I get 2 scroll bars, one for the body (as it should be) and one for the iframe.  Confusing the user.

Is there any way I can make the iframe be a height that gets rid of the scroll bar?

Changing body height to less than 100vh has no effect nor using % or px units.

*note:* I am not asking how to remove the banner. I am asking how to resize the iframe that houses the body **despite** the banner

thanks

EDIT:  Added after scroll screenshot showing the banner going off the screen.

EDIT2:  Ahh...Yes IE doesn't do it either, as well as FF.  Seems to be Chrome specific

EDIT 3:  also tried this style as per comments below

```
<style>
  html, body, iframe#sandboxFrame, .full_size {
        margin: 0  !important;
        padding: 0  !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100%  !important;
        background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
```

EDIT 4:  I've now raised an issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141889133)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also show "after scroll" pic. Added chrome tag because the issue isn't reproducible in Firefox. If the issue is reproducible in other browsers too, revert my edit.

Comment: thanks, have done so.  You are correct, seems to OK in IE too.  so maybe just a Chrome thing.

Comment: Try `overflow:hidden !important`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, no joy unfortunately.  I'm pretty sure now that this is bug in Chrome.  I've reported it as such, I'll report back if I get any progress.

Comment: If you have a issue tracker link, [edit] to add it in your question for wider reach.

Comment: great, thanks for that advice. I've added it in

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body, iframe#sandboxFrame, .full_size {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Deactivate these styles in the web browser using google chrome tools, then add 100vh to the element(s) that need it. You should be able to get the result you want then.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried those classes however the web app is going to be deployed as "anyone, even anonymous" so other users will not have those styles disabled.  It looks like it's a Chrome incompatibility.

Comment: yes, and pixels too.  Unfortunately no difference. It appears that the class that actually controls the height is as per the answer above "iframe#sandboxFrame, .full_size" . You can amend that height in the console manually.  But if inserted in the Apps CSS it appears to be overruled when the app is served from Google servers.

Comment: Use !important to overwrite the google css styles @MrPea

Comment: hmmm... didn't seem to affect anything, I'll edit the question to show what I did in case I've misunderstood !important

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and the div magically takes full height on a GAS WEB APP, but sorry that I am not experienced enough to explain further...

```
#divID {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SO.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.  The issue has been resolved now as of Chrome version 78 - there was a bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141889133  thanks again